# Read page headers and footer from Word.Range - VSTO Word Interop C#

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, vsto

I have a `Range` object and I want to use it to extract information from the page where the `Range` reside in. The information is in the headers and the footers inside a table, I want to read the text from the table.

I tried: `word.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.Range(ref pageNumber).TextFrame.TextRange.Text;`

Where word is a `Range` and `pageNumber` is the page number this range reside in.
The problem is I can't get the real page number! using `word.get_information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber)` returns incorrect page number!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer incase any1 is interested:

```
int i = (int)range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber) % 2;
WdHeaderFooterIndex index;
if (i == 0 && range.Sections[1].PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter == 1)
    index = WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages;
else
    index = WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary;

Range sRange = range.Sections[1].Range;
object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
sRange.Collapse(ref direction);
if (range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber) == sRange.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    && range.Sections[1].PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter == 1)
    index = WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage;

object rangeIndex = 1;
Range headerRange = range.Sections[1].Headers[index].Range.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange;

string profession = headerRange.Tables[1].Cell(4, 1).Range.Text;
string manPower = headerRange.Tables[1].Cell(4, 2).Range.Text;
string registration = headerRange.Tables[1].Cell(4, 3).Range.Text;
string taggingListNum = headerRange.Tables[1].Cell(4, 4).Range.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

read all text document. subsequently I use it to analyze and extract data:

```
        Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument; 

        string headers = "";

        foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
        {
            foreach (HeaderFooter hf in section.Headers)
            {
                headers += hf.Range.Text;
            }
        }

        string docText = headers + doc.Range(doc.Content.Start, doc.Content.End).Text;
```